# Given a random lat/lon, find nearest co-ordinate(lat/lon) from given the list of co-ordinates implying the direction of traveling

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, geospatial, google-distancematrix-api

Need to write below function to calculate distance given 3 inputs:

1. List of stops with coordinates, which also implies the direction of travelling. More like a polygon or which would form the closed loop.
2. Random co-ordinate around the loop.
3. One of the co-ordinate from the list given in point 1.

Need to find the distance between 2 and 3, keeping the direction of the loop in mind.

P.S., More like how Google is finding distance given two points given a route. But cant use Google APIs.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) you can find formulas and JS code to get distance between coordinates

```
JavaScript: 
var R = 6371e3; // metres
var φ1 = lat1.toRadians();
var φ2 = lat2.toRadians();
var Δφ = (lat2-lat1).toRadians();
var Δλ = (lon2-lon1).toRadians();

var a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
        Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
        Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

var d = R * c;
```

As far as I understand, you have to check distances between point and all stop nodes in order.

The smallest sum of distances of `P-S[i]` and `P-S[i+1]` reveals the most close segment to that point (does not work always - for example, for self-intersecting paths etc)

Comment: The catch here is we need to consider the route direction as well. This would not do that, I afraid.

Comment: Is considering stops in order enough? Or you mean something else?

Comment: Lets say A ---> B --> C ---> D ---> E ---> A is the route and order of stops. Given random point somewhere near/on the route, need to figure the next stop. Now let us say, the random point is near to C but has already crossed C; so next nearest is D stop. Need to calculate the distance to D and not to C.

Comment: I guess, the solution above would give distance to C! @Mbo hence, the direction is equally important.

Comment: As I said, **sum** of distance P-C and P-D for "good path" should be the smallest, so P lies near C-D segment and you know the next is D. Another way - seek for sthe shortest projection if point on segment. If it is guaranteed that P is almost exactly lies on the segment, you can also analyze directions (bearings) C-P and P-D